# how could i config to skip a transaction from recovering

Tags: mysql

I manually reboot system while mysql is loading data from a large csv file. Then when i restart mysqld, it crashed by throwing exception as following，
[image: mysql error log]

how could i config to skip this transaction from recovering?
As the error log showing, mysqld used up buffer size while rolling back a transaction, which buffer size should i need to tune?

Comment: Transaction can be either committed or rollbacked completely. No intermediate. So the answer is simple - this is impossible.

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much. If i need to recover the server, i have to dump the data, and then import to a new database? any other better choice?